# Hyper-V Ubuntu does not show installation wizard

Tags: system-installation, virtualization, hyper-v

I've got Ubuntu 20.04 installed via Hyper-V quick create with a 128Gb virtual HD.

I get to the home screen, but it just sits with the cursor spinning and does not show the install wizard (it has shown it once, but that got stuck so I turned off the VM and created a new one after trying again and just getting the spinning cursor):

[image]

Is there a way to trigger the install pop up from the cli?

I can access the terminal which loads quickly and I can ping outside my network successfully, so I don't think that it is an issue with resources or web access as I also have 4096Mb memory and 12 cores set up in settings.

I have created VMs in both hyper-V manager and in quick create, both of which have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It eventually did show up, albeit that I had to leave the VM running for over an hour before it did. After that, it seems to run correctly.